# Show that the convolution of the two time domain functions satisfy the relationship Y(q) = H(q) * U(q).

Tags: fourier-series

The convolution of two time domain functions h(t) and u(t) is given by
$$
y(t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t- \tau)u(\tau)d\tau
$$
Show that the Fourier Transforms Y(q), H(q) and U(q) satisfy the relation Y(q) = H(q) * U(q).

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! To be able to help you better, you are asked to show what you have tried yourself to answer your question. Moreover, the way your question is currently stated suggests that this question is homework which has been copied word for word onto the site. This behaviour is discouraged and frowned upon.

Comment: Look up any book on Fourier Analysis.